# How to put template class into args pack itself?

Tags: c++, templates

I have template class like below:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A;

template<typename ...Args>
class A<void(Args...)> {
public:
    void(*callback)(Args....);

    void foo(Args... args) {
        /* stuffs */
    }
};
```

Is it possible put `A<void(Args...)>` in Args pack itself while define specified class, like: `A<void(A<...>, /* other args */)>` ?
Make class something similar to:

```cpp
class B {
public:
    void(*callback)(const B&, /* other args */);

    void foo(const B&, /* other args */) {
        /* stuffs */
    }
};
```

I can make it work by using `void*` like `A<void(void*, /* other args */>`, then cast back to the original one inside the function. Just want to ask if it possible and how to do it, without using `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

I would let lambda/std::function combo do the heavy lifting.
It may result in a bit of overhead but the code becomes more maintainable and would look something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... args_t>
class A
{
public:
    template<typename fn_t> 
    auto register_callback(fn_t fn) // possibly constrain here (using SFINAE or concept)
    {
        m_callback = fn;
    }

    void func_with_callback(args_t&&... args)
    {
        m_callback(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(const args_t&...)> m_callback;
};

int main()
{
    std::string hello{"Hello"};
    A<std::string> a;

    // use lambdas to capture all the variables you need.
    a.register_callback([=](const std::string& name){ std::cout << hello << " " << name; });
    a.func_with_callback("Dave");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for making u confused about my question, the field in classes is just an example, it may be different. But what i need is `Args` list in template must be same as `Args` list in class's field, and must be same as `Args` list in `A<...>::foo()` and `A<...>` itself is once of `Arg` in `Args` list.

Comment: No problem ;) Just took me a few minutes to write this

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible put `A<void(Args...)>` in Args pack itself while define specified class, like: `A<void(A<...>, /* other args */)>` ?

Yes there is, as shown below. Note the added first argument  `const A<void(Args...)>&` in the definitions of `callback` and `foo`.

```
template<typename T>
class A;

template<typename ...Args>
class A<void(Args...)> { 
public:
//------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-------------->added this first argument
    void(*callback)(const A<void(Args...)>&, Args...);
//-----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------->added this first argument
    void foo(const A<void(Args...)>&,Args... args) {  
        
    }
}; 
void func(double, int)
{

}
int main()
{ 
      
    A<decltype(func)> a;
}
```

[Live demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/d8c7a160)

The above will result in an **instantiation of a class-type** like you want:

```
template<>
class A<void (double, int)>
{
  
  public: 
  void (*callback)(const A<void (double, int)> &, double, int);
  inline void foo(const A<void (double, int)> &, double __args1, int __args2);
  
  // inline A() noexcept = default;
};
```

---

Note that with injected class name you can just write `const A&` in the parameter list to make the code more readable.

```
template<typename ...Args>
class A<void(Args...)> { 
public:
//------------------------v---------------->injected class name
    void(*callback)(const A&, Args...);
//----------------------------------------->injected class name
    void foo(const A&,Args... args) {  
        
    }
};
```

[Demo with injected class name](https://cppinsights.io/s/f0d5bcc8)

Comment: Thank about your answer. I got that too. Because `A<void(Args...)>` may be used in case other than the question once ,so what i need is `Args` list in template must be same as `Args` list in class's field, and must be same as `Args` list in `A<...>::foo()`.

Comment: WIth [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name), `void (*callback)(const A&, double, int);` would even be enough.

Comment: @Ariz It is not clear what you're asking/saying. Feel free to ask a new separate question for you follow up questions and new requirements. Adding new requirements after there are already answers to the question such that it invalidates the answers should not be done.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, that will make the code much more readable. Updated.